# Not Playing indirect link, however direct link is working

Tags: php, html, href

I've got this code and it works with the direct links.
I've even got the parser working, so it pulls the free2viewtv list, however when i click on one of the links created using the parser, it doesnt work..

However if i click on 247 Retro TV, that works perfectly, i know thats due to the 247 Retro TV being the direct link.

But for the life of me, i just cannot see what is going wrong with

```
    <li>
       <a class="chlist" data-value="<?php echo $item['tvmedia']; ?>" href="javascript:void(0)";><?php echo $item['tvtitle']; ?></a>
    </li>
```

This is the full php.

```
    <?php
require_once 'parser-Free2ViewTV.php';
require_once 'config.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <h5 class="glow"><a href="Livestreams.php"></i>Free 2 View Web Player</h5></a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="list.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="hls.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css" media="all">
    <script src="player.js" async></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="videodiv">
             <video controls='none' id='myvideo' preload='none' tabindex='0'>
        <source id="primarysrc" src='none' type="application/x-mpegURL"/></video>
    </div>
    <div id="tvlist">
         <input  id="findfield" class="customSearch search" type="search" placeholder="find ..." />
<br>
      <ul id='playlist' class='list'>

<?php foreach ($items as $item) {?>
            <li><a class="chlist" data-value="<?php echo $item['tvmedia']; ?>" href="javascript:void(0)";><?php echo $item['tvtitle']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>

<li><a class='chlist' href='http://hlsdpi-cdn-chqtx02.totalstream.net/dpilive/247retro/ret/dai/playlist.m3u8'>247 Retro TV</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Parser being used is:-

```
<?php
$m3ufile = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geonsey/Free2ViewTV/master/Free2ViewTV-2020-Remote.m3u');
$m3ufile = str_replace('group-title', 'tvgroup', $m3ufile);
$m3ufile = str_replace('.ts', '.m3u8', $m3ufile);
$m3ufile = str_replace("tvg-", "tv", $m3ufile);
$re = '/#EXTINF:(.+?)[,]\s?(.+?)[\r\n]+?((?:https?|rtmp):\/\/(?:\S*?\.\S*?)(?:[\s)\[\]{};"\'<]|\.\s|$))/';
$attributes = '/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+?)="([^"]*)"/';
preg_match_all($re, $m3ufile, $matches);
$i = 1;
$items = array();
 foreach($matches[0] as $list) {
   preg_match($re, $list, $matchList);
   $mediaURL = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$matchList[3]);
   $mediaURL = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $mediaURL);
   $newdata =  array (
    'id' => $i++,
    'tvtitle' => $matchList[2],
    'tvmedia' => $mediaURL
    );
    preg_match_all($attributes, $list, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
       $newdata[$match[1]] = $match[2];
    }
     $items[] = $newdata;
 }
?>
```

I also tried

```
<li><a class="chlist" data-value="<?php echo $item['tvmedia']; ?>" href=$item['tvmedia'];><?php echo $item['tvtitle']; ?>
```

However the `$item['tvmedia'];` doesnt put the link into href

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `<a class="chlist" data-value="<?php echo $item['tvmedia']; ?>" href="javascript:void(0)";><?php echo $item['tvtitle']; ?></a>` isn't a real link. The href just does nothing. Unless you have some other Javascript which handles the click on this and does something with (what I assume is) the URL in the `data-value` attribute, then you can't expect this to work.

Comment: P.S. Why are you using such an old version of jQuery? Unless you need to support some ancient version of internet explorer then this shouldn't be necessary, use a recent one.

Comment: didnt think of the old JQuery, so updated and edited the code..

Comment: Thanks..that doesn't answer my question about the structure of your hyperlink though

Comment: well its meant to pull the link from the parser.. 
<li><a class="chlist" data-value="<?php echo $item['tvmedia']; ?>" href=$item['tvmedia'];><?php echo $item['tvtitle']; ?>
However the $item['tvmedia']; doesnt do the link into href=

Comment: Ok that's changed from your original code. You need to put the href value in quote marks and echo the value with PHP (just like you echo other values) e.g. `href="<?php echo $item['tvmedia']; ?>"`. That's assuming `$item['tvmedia'];` contains a valid URL

Comment: Thank You, i knew what i was trying to do, but couldnt see it.. and you answered it perfectly, the list of free to view channels loads perfectly now and works correctly.. Thank You @ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the href value in quote marks and echo the value with PHP (just like you echo other values) e.g.

```
href="<?php echo $item['tvmedia']; ?>"
```

That's assuming `$item['tvmedia']` contains a valid URL, of course :-)